# Setting up geolocation index in Aurelius Titan 0.5+

Tags: indexing, geolocation, titan

I am struggling to figure out how to set up a geolocation index, and how to use it, in titan 0.5.1.

Previously, in Titan 0.4 you could do the following:

```
g = rexster.getGraph("graph")

location = g.makeKey("location").dataType(Geoshape.class).indexed("search", Edge.class).make();
```

This does not work in the new 0.5 API. I have been looking through just about everything in the docs, and I have looked in the source itself without any luck.

How can this be achieved in Titan 0.5.1 and how can I use it after it is set up?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GraphOfTheGodsFactory](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/0.5.1/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java) code always shows how it's done in the current version.

```
// create type and index
final PropertyKey place = mgmt.makePropertyKey("place").dataType(Geoshape.class).make();
TitanGraphIndex eindex = mgmt.buildIndex("edges",Edge.class)
        .addKey(reason).addKey(place).buildMixedIndex(INDEX_NAME);

// insert data
ElementHelper.setProperties(hercules.addEdge("battled", nemean),
        "time", 1, "place", Geoshape.point(38.1f, 23.7f));
```

Querying is the same as in 0.4 (use `Geo.WITHIN` to search for points that fall within a given circle).